# Problem on LTSP Thin Client Startup with Edubuntu 14.04

Tags: edubuntu

I am working on a project where we have build(for free of course :-)) some computing labs on middle-high schools by the use of some old computers running Edubuntu via LTSP protocol. The client are Thin clients. 
Everything worked fine until we upgraded our server from Edubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. Then some Thin Client stopped working going on a sort of kernel panic during bootstrap. The strange thing is that a live of Edubuntu 14.04 booted via USB works fine on these clients. The problem involves just a subset of our computers, in particular the ones who share the same architecture(you can see the lshw next).
In particular, the error messages are the following:

[Error_Messages_pt1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X4FG.jpg)
[Error_Messages_pt2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZxjO.jpg)

Does anyone have some tips or had the same problem?
Tell me if you need other info about the problem.
Thank you all.

Comment: During these days we had some tries, but with no results. We tried to modify lts.conf file in order to modify some bootstrap properties like trying to disable quit splash in order to reduce the needed memory video or trying to switch from NBD to NFS but nothing changed. And some other little tries. We configured the client in orderd to use syslog tool to write log remotely on server, here is what client prints before going on error

https://github.com/genji993/DiffKernelLogEdubuntuLTSP

Finally, this is the lshw of clients that go on error:

http://pastebin.com/snQfYWBw

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by changing 'quiet splash' with 'quiet splash nomodeset' inside /opt/ltsp//boot/pxelinux.cfg/ltsp and running ltsp-update-kernels.